# TYPO3 11 News Extension 10.0.3: How to have pages for categories

Tags: typo3, url-routing, categories, typo3-extensions, tx-news

I am using `tx_news` with categories. Now I would like to have pages with url to each category like mypage.de/category/category1. On this page I see all news with category1.

I started with routing. According to
https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/10.0/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/Routing/Index.html
I added the part in "Basic setup (including categories, tags and the RSS/Atom feed)" into my site.yaml.

This works, when I use a fluid template for the detail view to list all categories:

```
<f:for each="{newsItem.categories}" as="category" iteration="iteratorCategories">
  <f:link.action
      pageUid="{category.shortcut}"
      arguments="{overwriteDemand:{categories:category.uid}}"
      class="news-list-category__item"
      title="{category.title}">
    {category.title}
  </f:link.action>
</f:for>
```

I get a list of all associated categories, which are linked as preset in the yaml file.

When I click on the link I get an error:

> (1/1) TypeError
> Return value of GeorgRinger\News\Controller\NewsBaseController::handleNoNewsFoundError() must be of the type string, null returned

What is going wrong?

I tried to find a full tutorial in the docs or in google but did not find anything

Is there somewhere a full tutorial for this?

How can I solve this?

Thank you, regards, Jürgen

Answer (score 0):

`\NewsBaseController::handleNoNewsFoundError()` has three return-point.

Two of them are returning `''` - a string.

So, there only the third left ([line 51](https://github.com/georgringer/news/blob/10.0.3/Classes/Controller/NewsBaseController.php#L151)):

```
$standaloneTemplate = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
$standaloneTemplate->setTemplatePathAndFilename(GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($options[1]));
return $standaloneTemplate->render();
```

Not sure, when rendering returns `null`. But I would check the configuration around templates, their paths, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. `pageUid="{category.shortcut}"` returned `null`. It is from a deprecated viewhelper. `<f:link.page pageUid="798" additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1:{overwriteDemand:{categories: category}}}" title="Alle Artikel zu {category.title}">{category.title}</f:link.page>` is working